Is there any to automate the process of Quality assurance for data and campaigns in SFMC?
Currently, our team does a lot of manual work for Quality assurance to validate data in data extensions and checks on the campaigns to make sure they are going to the correct population.
Is there any way to automate Quality assurance process for data extensions like running scripts that spit out reports? OR if there is any app in appexchange for SFMC that does that?

How would you define “quality”? It is quite subjective. You could build your own solution to validate e.g. size of your campaign DEs, but it will be difficult to build a completely automated QA process

Hi @LukasLunow I understand the quality assurance processes needs to be custom based on individual campaigns and requirements. By "quality", I meant checking the data integrity, dates are in future (not expired), running exclusion checks to make sure non of the excluded customer is showing up in the case etc. I think one way to automate is to build custom sql queries to perform quality checks as doing this manually for multiple campaigns within SFMC takes a lot of time. I wanted to ask if anyone got any ideas or there are apps out there to do this?
